# Reactjs - correct way of inherit props to first level children and nested children

Tags: reactjs

In my case I try to create a simple Form Component - mostly for "testing" reactjs and work with it.

To do this I work with 2 Components. The first Component is the Parent, the "Form" Component. The second Component is the field of the form - for example a simple textfield. This is the markup it would look like:

```
<Form
  schema={MyFormSchema}
>
   <Input name="name" />
   <Input name="age" />
</Form>
```

In MyFormSchema I have all information which I need for every Child of the type "Input". For this case I have done this in my "Form" Component:

Form.jsx

```
Form = React.createClass({
  renderChildren() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child)=>{
      if (child.type && child.type.prototype && child.type.prototype.constructor.displayName === 'Input') {
        let additionalProps = {
            fieldSchema: this.props.schema.pick(child.props.name),
            onChange: this.onChange
        };
        return React.cloneElement(child, additionalProps);
      }
      return child;
    });
  },
  render() {
    return(
      <form>
        {this.renderChildren()}
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

What I am doing here is to "clone" every "input" child and add some new props depending on the schema.

So the first question is:

**Is this really the correct war in reactJs ?** When I am not "cloning" every element and adding new properties I have to add the property directly in my View, right ? Something like  but I am trying to prevent this because all information I need I already have as a prop in my Form Schema.

After playing around with this I found out, that this.props.children only have the first level of children. But when I have nested my Children in my `Form` Component it will not work anymore that my Component is replacing the `Input` Component with the manipulated component.

Example:

```
<Form
  schema={MyFormSchema}
>
   <AnotherComponent>
       <Input name="name" />
   </AnotherComponent>
   <Input name="age" />
</Form>
```

When I am doing it like I now doing it this code will not work anymore because in this.props.children I only have [AnotherComponent, Input[name=age]] and the Input[name=name] is missing. **So I think the way I am doing it is the wrong way.** But i am not sure.

So the main question is:

**Like in my example: What is the correct way in ReactJs to inherit props (or what ever) to all children (also the nested one) - or is this not possible in the "react" way and I really have to pass all necessary props to all children ?**

Edit:

When I am talking about "pass all necessary props to all children" I mean something like this:

```
<Form
  schema={MyFormSchema}
>
   <AnotherComponent>
       <Input name="name" fieldSchema={this.getFieldSchema('name')} onChange={this.onChange} />
   </AnotherComponent>
   <Input name="age" fieldSchema={this.getFieldSchema('age')} onChange={this.onChange} />
</Form>
```

In this example I would pass all necessary props I want to add dynamically by the parent. In my example above the next problem would be: "this" would not work for the name input because of its parent AnotherComponent. So I would have to reference to the parent - of course: its possible, but I think it would be a ugly way.

Comment: Do you have any control over the `Input` component?

Comment: What type of control you are talking about ? If you mean if I am the person who is adding the <Input /> Components to my View: Yes!

Comment: I meant did you write/can you change the `Input` component? (Or are you using React-Bootstrap or something similar?)

Comment: The Input component is my own - so I am able to control them, yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three correct ways to deeply pass props:

1) Just actually pass them down the tree from each component to the next (this is the most readable (in terms of code logic), but can get unwieldy once you have too many props to pass and lots of levels in your tree.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';    

var GrandParent = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <Parent familyName={'componentFamily'} />
    );
  }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <Child familyName={props.familyName} />
    );
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  render () {
    return (
      <p>{'Our family name is ' + props.familyName}</p>
    );
  }
});
```

2) Use a [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/)-style store (I prefer [Reflux](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs), though [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux) is all the rage right now) to keep a common state. All components can then access that store. For me at least, this is the current preferred method. It's clear and it keeps business logic out of the components.

Example (using Reflux):

```
import React from 'react';
import Reflux from 'reflux';

var MyStore = Reflux.createStore({
  // This will be called in every component that connects to the store
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      // Contents of MyFormSchema here
    };
  }
});

var Input = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  },
  mixins: [Reflux.connect(MyStore)],
  render () {
    // I don't know what MyFormSchema so I'm generalizing here, but lets pretend its a map that uses the name of each field a key and then has properties of that field within the map stored at the key/value
    return (
      <input type={this.state[name].type} name={this.props.name} value={this.state[name].type} />
    );
  }
});
```

3) Use React's [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) feature. As you'll see immediately from looking at the docs, this feature is still in development and is subject to possible change and even removal in future versions of React. So, while it is likely the easiest way to pass props down a tree of components, personally I'm staying away from it until it becomes more of a finalized feature.

I'm not going to write an example for this one since the docs make it very clear. However, make sure to scroll down on the doc page and take a look at [Parent-child coupling](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#parent-child-coupling), which is kind of what you're doing right now.

Another solution for you is that instead of having a single component that renders `Form` and its `Input`s, why not just pass the prop to Form as you do currently, and then simply render the individual `Input` using `Form`'s `render()`.

Comment: I will check the Reflux thing! But: When I add this store to my parent Component and all the children are connecting to this store the children will have access to all states and props in this store ? Or is this just a "schema" ?

Comment: Actually, in the example I have you connect each `Input` to the store, not the `Form`. Traditionally using Reflux you would have a store per-component type (assuming that component needs a state). So, the `Input` components should access an `InputStore` that has only the information needed by the `Input`s, which in your case happens to be the `MyFormSchema` object. As far as I can tell, your `Form` component doesn't need state at all (unless the number of `Input`s are dynamic). Just store an array of names in the `Form's `getDefaultProps`. Does that help?

Comment: In my case "MyFormSchema" is dynamicly and will be added as a prop of <Form /> then it would be nice to inherit this prop to the <Input /> Components (maybe with some adjustments). As I see is this not the case to use Reflux, right ?

Comment: That's correct. In that case you will want to follow example 1 I have. Basically: the `render()` function of the top level component renders `Form` and the `render()` of `Form` then renders each `Input` component, passing each either the entire `MyFormSchema` or just the information from it that it needs.

Answer (score 5):

You could use react-addons-clone-with-props package this way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import cloneWithProps from 'react-addons-clone-with-props';

// ...

class Form extends Component {
  recursivelyMapChildren(children) {
    return React.Children.map(children, child => {
      if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
        return child;
      }

      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        ...child.props,
        children: this.recursiveCloneChildren(child.props.children)
      });
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>{this.recursivelyMapChildren(this.props.children)}</form>
    );
  }
}
```

What the code does:

1. Gets all the children components via predefined `children` prop (see [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html)).
2. Recursively maps the collection of children with `React.Children.map` method, applying a lambda function to each element.
3. Saves the mapped (i.e. updated, but not mutated!) children elements into `mappedChildren` constant.
4. Puts them within `form` DOM element.

It looks simple and it should be so.

But you have to keep in mind that React is great when your code is kept clean and transparent. When you explicitly pass props like

```
<Form
  schema={MyFormSchema}
>
   <Input
     name="name"
     schema={MyFormSchema} />
   <Input
     name="age"
     schema={MyFormSchema} />
</Form>
```

there's way less things to get broken when you accidentally change the underlying logic.

Comment: But this is what I am already doing. One of my problems are the nested children (I think this will also not work in your example ?). Where is the difference like its now ? I am using React.cloneElement instead of cloneWithProps but the result should be the same.

Comment: Oh I see! You need to map children recursively. Updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks but you dont have to edit your answer for a recursively way. I already have done this in my. My question would be: Is this relay the correct way ? Looking recursively for nested children and manipulate them ? What do you think ?

Comment: Actually, passing props directly would be more "React way" than populating props in a concealed way. The more transparent your code is, the better. If you want to expand props, see [this ES7 feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (or use underscode/lodash instead). But the best way would be to pass props explicitly, whatever the structure is, and simplify the structure instead of trying to automate things that otherwise shouldn't be.

Comment: Absolutely understanding. But in my case it would be like a mess. When creating a Form with my component you have to pass around 3 props to each input field which are depending on the props of the parent component. So its just like "copy and paste" - i want to prevent this by adding the props automatically.

Comment: Note: react-addons-clone-with-props has been deprecated. Use the built-in function `React.cloneElement()` instead now. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement

Answer (score 2):

Thankyou. Credits @Rishat Muhametshin

I have used the above to create a re-usable method.
This works beautifully:

**utils/recursivelyMapChildren.jsx**

```
const recursivelyMapChildren = (children, addedProperties) => {

        return React.Children.map(children, child => {
            if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
                return child;
            }

            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                ...child.props,
                ...addedProperties,
                children: this.recursivelyMapChildren(child.props.children, addedProperties)
            });
        })
 };
export default recursivelyMapChildren;
```

usecase:

**Form.jsx**

```
import recursivelyMapChildren from 'utils/recursivelyMapChildren';
class Form extends Component {

    handleValidation(evt, name, strValidationType){
/* pass this method down to any nested level input field */
    }

    render(){

        return (
            <form>
                {recursivelyMapChildren(this.props.children, {
                    handleValidation: this.handleValidation.bind(this)
                })}

                <input type="submit" value="submit" className="validation__submit"/>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
export default Form
```

**SomeExample.jsx**

```
const SomeExample = () => {
    return (
        <Form>
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Personal details</legend>
                <div className="formRow">
                    <InputText/>    {/* This component will receive the method - handleValidation, so it is possible to update the state on the nested grand parent - form */}      
                </div>
                <div className="formRow">
                    <InputText/>{/* This component will receive the method - handleValidation, so it is possible to update the state on the nested grand parent - form */}  
                </div>  
            </fieldset>
        </Form>
    )
}

export default SomeExample;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternate solution to pass props to nested children. The function createFormComponents takes the schema and produces an object of components that will receive props as usual but with the schema already provided. You could link the FormContainer in my example up to a store or use setState to handle changes to the schema over time and the children will update correctly.

The example's output is to the console to demonstrate that the props are received as expected.

```
function Form_(props) {
    console.log('Form props', props)
    return <div>{props.children}</div>
}

function Input_(props) {
    console.log('Input props', props)
    return <div />
}

function createFormComponents(schema) {
    return {
        Form: props => {
            return Form_({ ...props, schema })
        },

        Input: props => {
            return Input_({ ...props, schema })
        },
    }
}

const FormContainer = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        const myFormSchema = { x: 0, y: 1, z: 2 }
        const {
            Form,
            Input,
        } = createFormComponents(myFormSchema)

        return (
            <Form>
                <Input name="name" />
                <Input name="age" />
            </Form>
        )
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(
    <FormContainer />,
    document.getElementById('container')
)
```

Fiddle: [Props Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ben173/3k7v3rhp/2/)