# React inherite HTML elements props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello is it possible to inherit props from a HTML button or HTML input element?
I only found solutions with typescript here: [Extending HTML elements in React and TypeScript while preserving props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731352/extending-html-elements-in-react-and-typescript-while-preserving-props)

but with plain Javascript React i didnt found a solution.

Comment: Remember that TypeScript is just Javascript with types. In the end, it's translated to JS. `extends` is a JS keyword, so it works both in TS and JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs - correct way of inherit props to first level children and nested children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484307/reactjs-correct-way-of-inherit-props-to-first-level-children-and-nested-childr)

Comment: @EldarB. no I want to inherit HTML Button or Input props

Comment: @EldarB. Then I am using typescript in javascript files and i get this warning Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files. So the solution was to switch to typescript?

Comment: No, just use plain JS. Don't add types.